# How do I sort a computed property by a value?

Tags: json, vue.js

After looking at [Vue.JS' documentation][1], we're provided with a method which, as an example, sorts by all even numbers. That's all good, but I'd like to sort an array by a name value inside an array - meaning I need to do a comparison. All the answers I've found have since been deprecated and the only solutions are using other modules than VueJS itself. Is this really not possible or am I just missing something obvious?
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

Here's my example:

```
data() {
    return {
        namesArray: []
        ]
    };
  },
...
computed: {
    addToNamesArray(){
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Charles', "lastName": 'Charleston'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Albert', "lastName": 'Alberterson'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Bertrand', "lastName: ''"})
        return this.namesArray
        //(Obviously more complicated in reality, but let's keep it simple)
    }
}
```

and in Vue:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(namesList, index) in addNamesToArray" :key="index">
        {{namesList.firstName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Trying to sort within the computed property returns a "Unexpected side effect in computed property"-error, because one can't mutate inside a computed property. So my second try was making a method:

```
methods: {
    sortNames(){
        this.namesArray.sort((a,b) => a.firstName- b.firstName)
    }
}
```

resulting in the new computed property:

```
computed: {
    addToNamesArray(){
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Charles', "lastName": 'Charleston'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Albert', "lastName": 'Alberterson'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Bertrand', "lastName: ''"})
        this.sortNames()
        return this.namesArray
    }
}
```

but this does nothing(???)

I'd be really grateful if someone can explain to me why these solutions doesn't work and provide me with a one <3

Comment: exactly as the error message states. you should not be mutating the data i.e. `this.namesArray.push` should not exist.

Comment: Computed property functions should compute and return a _new_ property. They should not modify an existing property, particularly if that property is a dependency of the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's start from the beginning:

I think you should start with moving addToNamesArray() from **computed** to the **methods**. So you can be sure it's only called once, computed will be called more often when your data changes.

your function sortNames should be moved to the computed field, like so:

```
mounted(){
    this.addToNamesArray()
},
computed: {
     sortedNames(){
          return this.namesArray.concat().sort((a,b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName))
     }
},
methods: {
     addToNamesArray(){
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Charles', "lastName": 'Charleston'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Albert', "lastName": 'Alberterson'})
        this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Bertrand', "lastName": ''})
     }
}
```

The reason for placing it in the computed property, instead of the methods is that this makes the value reactive, if namesArray now gains another element, the whole list is properly rerendered once. Methods don't do this correctly.
We create a 'copy' of the namesArray to not touch the data in the object itself, since that will also trigger a rerender.

In Vue you can now do:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(namesList, index) in sortedNames" :key="index">
        {{namesList.firstName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The reason it's not sorting is because 'string'-'string' = NaN in javascript, so I replaced it with localeCompare

Comment: The 'string'-'string' = NaN got me, just now. It fails silently so it's hard to spot. Adding a compare function fixes it.   if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;

Answer (score 1):

Few issues here:-

1. You should not modify `this.namesArray` inside `computed` as the computed property will re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed. This might create side-effect as items might be inserted into `this.namesArray` multiple times.
2. So, update `this.namesArray` inside `created` method
3. and simply sort the array by `firstName` inside `addNamesToArray` computed property using [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data() {
    return {
      namesArray: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Charles',"lastName": 'Charleston'})
    this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Albert',"lastName": 'Alberterson'})
    this.namesArray.push({"firstName": 'Bertrand',"lastName": 'Doe'})
  },
  computed: {
    addNamesToArray() {
      return this.namesArray.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(namesList, index) in addNamesToArray" :key="index">
      {{namesList.firstName}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That explained the problem to me, but it didn't work in my context - because the data I'm handling (in reality, not the above example code HAS to be computed). But thank you so much for the explanation - that helped a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, because it's [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) it will update when `this.namesArray` updates.

```
computed: {
    sortedNamesArray() {
        return this.namesArray.sort((a,b) => a.firstName - b.firstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: this still gave the "Unexpected side effect in computed property" error

Comment: @Nivyan My bad, thought you were adding to the array as part of the demo. As the other answers suggest, you shouldn't update the array in the computed.

Comment: Exactly :D That's what I had to wrap my head around.